# About Polkadot's new mint token How much of it goes to the treasury?

Tags: treasury

Is there any way to find out how many of the tokens from the new mint on Polkadot/Kusama have been given to treasury?

Answer (score 0):

Check this website: https://www.dotreasury.com/dot/

[image]

You can see the income of the treasury and you can go [here](https://www.dotreasury.com/dot/income) and see more in detail and see where is coming from and when.